# Find a string inside quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

The title explains my problem. I am trying to get a string that has quotation marks around it so I can use Node.js to pass into a weather module. Here's my code so far (I have not set the var `CityToSearch` yet in this code which is what I need help with)
And also yes I'm using Discord.js to send messages.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const PREFIX = '/';
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
const weather = require('weather-js')

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {return}
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  switch (args[0]) {
case 'weather':
if (args.includes('"')){
        var CityToSearch = 
      }
      weather.find({search: `city, ${CityToSearch}`, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
              if(err) console.log(err);
              var currentw = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x00ffff)
                .setTitle(`Current Weather in ${args[1]} in state ${args[2]}`)
                .addField('Temperature', result[0].current.temperature)
                .addField('Sky Text', result[0].current.skytext)
                .addField('Humidity', result[0].current.humidity)
                .addField('Wind Speed & Direction', result[0].current.winddisplay)
                .addField('Feels Like', result[0].current.feelslike)
                .addField('Location', result[0].current.observationpoint)
                .addField('Time', result[0].current.observationtime)
                .addField('Date', result[0].current.date)
              message.channel.send(currentw)
            });
```

Comment: Can you show us the input string? Gonna be hard to help you otherwise...

Comment: this is an example input string. the code splices by spaces using `args.splice(' ')`. Example: `/weather "San Fransico" California`. I want `San Fransico` to become `CityToSearch`.

Comment: Can you update the question with the "edit" button please? I'll add an answer using a simple regex

Comment: ok I did that. also dont mind my syntax because my copy and paste is practically broken.

Comment: Would setting `CityToSearch` to `'${args[1]} ${args[2]}'` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the actual string with `"`. So that the string will be split and the string at index `1` will be the city you are looking for.

```js
const str = '/weather "San Fransico" California';
console.log(str.split('"'));
console.log(str.split('"')[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code already spliced `args` with spaces, so now it would split it again with the code you gave.

Comment: You can change that earlier code to `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split('"')` and within the `switch(args[0])` block check for `case "/weather ":`.

Comment: The code already checks for specific args as the first one, each beginning with `/` and the rest containing a command. This one specific command `/weather` checks weather already using `case 'weather'`. The code also automatically takes out the prefix (in this case `/`)

Comment: Or you can simply do the splitting with `message.content` itself. Like `message.content.split('"')[1]`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I tested it before I used it in the weather Node.js module and it logged `san fransico` when i logged CityToSearch which was equal to `message.content.split('"')[1]`

Answer (score 1):

I would NOT split the arguments on spaces initially. You can use the Regular Expression below with your arguments to yank out the command, and then parse the inputs as needed:

```
const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).match(/\/([^\s]+) (.+)/)
if (args) {  // valid input?
  const command = args[1]
  const input = args[2]

  switch (command) {
    case 'weather':
      const cityMatch = input.match(/"([^"]+)"/)
      const CityToSearch = (cityMatch) ? cityMatch[1] : input.split(/\s/)[0]
      weather.find({search: `city, ${CityToSearch}` ...)
   
    // other commands...

  }
}
```

Comment: There are other commands as well so taking out the `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')` would break the rest of the code.

Comment: I see... then you need to delineate different pieces. You said the input was `/weather "San Fransico" California` is that not correct? What else is there? I think you can do this with a regular expression easily, but you would need to know the full content of the input.

Comment: For example, if the command ALWASY starts with "/" and is one word (no spaces), then you can do a regex to figure that out. The point is, you should NOT split the whole thing on spaces...

Comment: Yes, that was the input. There are no other args.